# What do I need to look out for when converting 9V example schematics to 12V?

Tags: analog, 12v, component-selection

What do I need to look out for when converting 9V example schematics to 12V?

Most of my ICs work until 18V, and it seems to me all the resistor divider stuff is based on ratios, so it should scale (correct?).

For LED resistors etc the 9V resistors should be more or less within the tolerances.

I usually need to do this for things like comparators in light sensor circuits and things like that: not incredibly complex, but i am constantly wanting adapting them to 12V for using relays, large batteries etc.

The thing I am not sure about for instance, is that for say a [LDR based light sensor](http://www.electroschematics.com/4129/photodiode-design-note/) using a voltage divider and comparator it should effect the sensitivity right?
The reaction of LDR is the same but the voltage is higher so that swing represents a smaller change in the ratios.
This seems like it would be minimal..

Anything else to keep in mind, or is such a small voltage increase not usually a problem?

Example schematics:

[image] [image]

I am at the stage in electronics where I can decipher and understand the idea what circuits are doing and understand datasheets, but I am pretty sloppy still with all the calculations stuff!

Comment: It would help if you posted the schematic or a link to it.  Check capacitor voltage ratings.  If you have an LDO, it will be dissipating more heat, so its heat sink should be adequate.

Comment: cheers, I put a link to a simple light sensor already its about the calibre of the things i always want to convert at the moment.

Other examples would be this touch switch, containing transistors... would they hold up in a Voltage increased schematic? The current should me the same right?

http://www.electroschematics.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/08/electronic-touch-switch.jpg

Comment: You mention batteries - so are you talking about a solid, regulated 12v power source or a nominal 12v battery source which may be in the range 9v-15v (approx) depending on state of charge?

Answer (score 4):

> but i am constantly wanting adapting them to 12V for using relays,
>   large batteries etc.

Why not make a small switching buck regulator - the circuits newly attached to the 12V battery (via the regulator) will take smaller currents to power them from the 12V.

After all isn't this another valid point - you are moving to bigger batteries to make the circuits operate for longer as well?

The amount of time you'd go to (possibly) to make the circuits work from new supplies would be better spent looking up a buck regulator and implementing it.

Answer (score 2):

For the two circuits you provide, no, a change to 12v would not require any changes. Well, except for replacing that 6v lamp with a 12v one. Voltage dividers do work on ratios, but as the voltage goes up, so does the current the voltage dividers will conduct. The increase in voltage divider current from 9v to 12v is minimal though. Same for led current using the same series resistor.

Once you get into higher voltages, or you start using ics that only accept 5v, then you would have to start using step down regulators. Also keep in mind capacitors. 10v capacitors with a 12v power supply will cause problems, so you would have to replace those. Depending on the transistor (none of the common hobbyist ones), a higher voltage might mean they should be replaced with ones that can accept that voltage. Again, not in this case.